# How do I give the hankie to Le Chuck

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se

I try to give the clean white hankie to Le Chuck in the PC special edition of monkey island 2, but whenever I take the hankie in my hand and wait at the door for him to arrive, he doesn't. It seems like Le Chuck only appears, while I don't have the hankie in my hand.

Is there a pattern, how often and when Le Chuck appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He really doesn't appear when it's selected, so don't have it selected. How often he appears is simply random. There is only little time to give him the hankie after he appears. You probably need a mouse to achieve it fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found it only possible to do by switching to classic mode